# Partitions on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04

How can I expand the Boot partition on Ubuntu 14.04.2 as it keeps telling me I have very little space left on that partition and I don't want to uninstall any files as I don't know what is necessary and what isn't?

Comment: How big is it currently?

Comment: I don't know how big it is meskobalazs, I'm beginning to think Ubuntu was a bad choice for me as I am not an IT professional. I thought the transition from Windows 7 would be an easy one but it has been very problematic!

Answer (score 3):

You probably have loads of old kernels installed. You can remove some of them as follows:

First check your current kernel (you definitely do not want to remove that one)

```
uname -r
```

Then check which are installed with:

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
```

And to remove an old kernel:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-OLDVERSION
```

Replace `OLDVERSION` with the version of the old kernel you want to remove

Afterwards update grub with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

(Updating grub is not strictly necessary since it should run automatically after you uninstall an old kernel, but it does no harm)

Comment: Thanks Limecat, however I do not know what you are talking about. What am I supposed to do with all of this?

Comment: Every time you upgrade to a new Linux Kernel, the old one remains on your system. This is by design, since your system might be unusable with a new kernel and that way you can still go back to a previous 'working' version. Over time these old kernels build up inside /boot (your boot partition). If you look inside /boot you will see the kernel files (vmlinuz, initrd, etc). The point is that if you run out of space on /boot, then just uninstall some of your older kernels. Each uninstall will free up around 40MB.

Comment: Hi Limecat, I tried the above in 'Command Line' however it kept asking for my password but then wouldn't let me write in my password. Any ideas as to how I can overcome this?